# How to add new vertex using gremlin coalesce when the traversal is empty?

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3, gremlin-java

I am using `@GremlinDsl` so my traversal from `g.V().hasLabel('NEW')`, so I am using `coalesce` to add new vertices. It works well when there is any vertex with the given `LABEL` in the database, otherwise, it throws an exception. It's obvious the traversal is empty from `g.V().hasLabel('NEW')`.

```
g.V().hasLabel('NEW').coalesce(__.V().hasId('T12321321R'),
__.addV('NEW')
.property(T.id, 'T12321321R'))
```

How to solve this, when we create the given vertex(Label) for the first time in the database? Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need conditional write through fold and unfold.

```
gremlin> g.V()

gremlin> g.V().
......1>   hasLabel('NEW').
......2>   hasId('T12321321R').
......3>   fold().
......4>   coalesce(unfold(), addV('NEW').property(T.id, 'T12321321R'))
==>v[T12321321R]

gremlin> g.V()
==>v[T12321321R]

gremlin> g.V().
......1>   hasLabel('NEW').
......2>   hasId('T12321321R').
......3>   fold().
......4>   coalesce(unfold(), addV('NEW').property(T.id, 'T12321321R'))
==>v[T12321321R]

gremlin> g.V()
==>v[T12321321R]
```